# .NET 4.5 ZipFile class not producing consistent files

Tags: .net, zip, md5

Maybe I am just not understanding Zip files... Here is what I have. I am using code pasted below to zip my java workspace and push it to a network drive. The intent is that I will have this run on PC login. I have all of my java windows closed, I run the tool twice. I produces 2 zips of the same byte length but different MD5s, according to .NET and a linux system that I copied them to.

However, when I manually use 7zip to create a zip file from my java directory, I do it 2 separate times and the files have the same MD5.

Can any one either verify this issue or provide some insight into what could cause this? To my understanding zip files should be repeatable, there is no like random Seed or anything in the algorithm. 
This code was compiled with VS2012 and with the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem stuff linked in assembly.

```
 Public Sub New(sourceDir As String, baseName As String)
        s = sourceDir
        t = t + baseName + ".zip"
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(s, t, Compression.CompressionLevel.NoCompression, False)
        Dim stream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(t)
        Dim md5 As System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
        hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream))
        md5.Dispose()
        stream.Close()
        Dim file As New System.IO.FileInfo(t)
        fname = baseName + "." + hash + ".zip"
        t = file.DirectoryName + "\" + fname
        file.MoveTo(t)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do the tests show that the file is valid? ZIP file format has some unused fields and if they are I can imagine garbage in them, which will affect the checksum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a guess, but the Zip header spec includes a fields for [`File last modification date/time`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29). Most likely this is being set to the file creation time, which will be different between the two runs.

It would be easy enough for you to check if this is the case with a binary file editor.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that, weird that zips created by 7z at separate times would not have that issue. But it is definitively something to look into. Maybe I can override it to use the last modified date of the folder according to windows

Comment: Yup, it looks like it was that. I guess I will have to use a different archive format or a library that lets me declare the datetime field. Thanks