# zip a file programatically like native send to compressed zip folder

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I have to send a zipped file to an external application. Support on the other end says the application fails to read my programatically created file. This is how i create the file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

const string ZIPPATH = @".\stock.zip";
const string PACKAGEPATH = @".\stock\content";
const string APPPACKAGE = @".\stock";
const string PACKAGEFILENAME = @"content\Offers.xml";

private void CreateZipArchive()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(PACKAGEPATH)) Directory.CreateDirectory(PACKAGEPATH);

    if (File.Exists(ZIPPATH)) File.Delete(ZIPPATH);

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(APPPACKAGE, ZIPPATH);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(ZIPPATH, FileMode.Open))
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry zae = archive.CreateEntry(PACKAGEFILENAME);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(zae.Open(), new UTF8Encoding(true)))
        {
           // xml writing code ...
            sw.Write("--snipped--");
        }
    }
}
```

the folder APPPACKAGE contains some required files. After zip creation I insert my created xml file. inspecting the contents of the created zip file everything *looks* right yet the recipient application fails to read it. My question is: Is there something I might have missed?

**Edit:** Client gave me little additional Feedback. The only thing mentioned was that filure to read the package can happen if there is an md5 error. I suspect now that it could be related to the order in which I create the package. I'll try to first create the xml file and then create the zip file

Comment: What is a "recipient application"?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I send the zip file to a REST Api. The "recipient application" is an application I have no control over, behind the REST endpoint.

Comment: Did you ask client what kind of error he see in his REST Api? Do you have logs from him? It would help with investigation.
You can also try prepare zip file, but using Windows build-in function from context menu and send it to REST Api to ensure if issue is indeed in your program.

Comment: good point! I just asked for exactly that. until I get the response, the only clue I got is, that the application accepts my files when they are manually put into a zip file.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I just tested manually generating through the context menu and it is sucessfully recieved by REST Api. Inspecting both zip files I see no difference. they have both the exact same size and both were generated by Deflate algorithm

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I got a response from the client. I updated my question accordingly

Comment: Maybe your issue is related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864039/net-4-5-zipfile-class-not-producing-consistent-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although LukaszSzczygielek pointed out [another possible Issue in zip file creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864039/net-4-5-zipfile-class-not-producing-consistent-files) the solution of my particular problem is to first create the files and then create the package:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

const string ZIPPATH = @".\stock.zip";
const string PACKAGEPATH = @".\stock\content";
const string APPPACKAGE = @".\stock";
const string PACKAGEFILENAME = @"\Offers.xml";

private void CreateZipArchive()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(PACKAGEPATH)) Directory.CreateDirectory(PACKAGEPATH);

    if (File.Exists(ZIPPATH)) File.Delete(ZIPPATH);

    string fileFullPath = PACKAGEPATH + PACKAGEFILENAME;
    using(Stream fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, new UTF8Encoding(true)))
    {
        // xml writing code ...
        sw.Write("--snipped--");
    }

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(APPPACKAGE, ZIPPATH);
}
```